# hide specific things on tumblr pages

Tags: tumblr

so i recently started making tumblr layouts again but i suddenly don't know how to do this, i've tried

```
{block:Pages}
#notes { display: none; }
{/block:Pages}
```

even tried

```
{block:HasPages}
#notes { display: none; }
{/block:HasPages}
```

if i use permalink i hide it perfectly fine but it hides everything or every individual page, i'm just trying to hide them from specific pages. Would i have to make a custom layout page and just edit it from there? Or is there an actual way to hide a div in a specific tumblr page?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `{block:Date}{/block:Date}` blocks. They only show up when something has a date associated with them (ie not on ask pages or other pages). You should also wrap them in `{block:PermalinkPage}{/block:PermalinkPage}` as well so it only shows up on the permalink page.

Also, instead of adding CSS to hide the element, it's better to wrap the element in the blocks so they don't show up at all on those pages.